Waves on a bounded string
I am trying to apply a "piecing together of solutions in space" method, like one often uses in introductory quantum mechanics for 1D potential steps, to the 1D wave equation in a bounded domain, with a boundary where the wave speed changes abruptly. For example, where two strings of different mass per unit length are connected.
I would appreciate any input on both the setup and the solution method, as at the moment I cannot understand where I go wrong. Here is how I understand the setup, denoting by $f(x, t)$ the wave function, in the string example that being the transverse displacement from equilibrium of the string:
$$f_{xx} - \epsilon (x) f_{tt} = 0$$
with the subscripts indicating the partial derivative order and variable, for example $f_{xx} \equiv \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$, and with
$$\epsilon(x) = \epsilon_1 \quad \text{if} \quad 0 \leq x < a-l \\ \epsilon(x) = \epsilon_2 \quad \text{if} \quad a-l \leq x \leq a$$
defining the two regions, where $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are positive real numbers. Denoting by $f_1$ and $f_2$ the solution in the respective region, the boundary conditions are:
$$
f_1 (0, t) = 0 \\ f_2 (a, t) = 0 \\ f_1 (a-l, t) = f_2 (a-l, t) \\ f_{1,x}(a-l, t) = f_{2,x} (a-l, t)
$$
the latter two essentially saying that the strings are joined "smoothly". The initial conditions can be, for example, that the string starts static and plucked perfectly in the middle:
$$
f_1(x,0) = f_2(x,0) = \sin(\frac{x}{a} \pi) \\
f_{1,t}(x,0) = f_{2,t}(x,0) = 0
$$
I then try a solution by separation of variables, and for the spatial part the Fourier series seems appropriate, giving for each term, upon solving the equation in time, the specific temporal dependency given below:
$$
f(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} [A_n \sin(k_n x) + B_n \cos (k_n x)][C_n \sin(\omega_n t) + D_n \cos(\omega_n t)]
$$
with $\omega_n = k_n / \sqrt{\epsilon}$. If we now focus on the solution in region 1, then $k_n = n \pi / (a-l)$ for the Fourier series of a function bounded in region 1. Substituting the first boundary condition (at $x = 0$), one finds that $\forall n: \  B_n = 0 $.
With only the sine series remaining, the problem is that this automatically means $f_1(a-l, t) = 0 $ which makes sense as Fourier series represents a periodic function, however, it means that there is an obvious oversight in this solution attempt that I am missing.
